# Why Is Main site not giving appropriate badge for reading FAQ?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro, badges

Have mentioned this in chat a few weeks ago and as others have referred to SE system in other answers here in meta thought would ask for advice regarding the reasons or possibilities to why i have not been awarded the [image] for reading FAQ in main site.

When i view FAQ there are highlighted text which appears to be directing me in how to use this site more appropriately. i.e.
[image: What i see in FAQ]

Have probably referred to FAQ more than new most users, (some posting in meta mentioning they were unaware of the brilliant About page even after nearly a year using this site!) and as i have not been awarded the appropriate badge for my efforts would like to ask Why?

Edit: For confirmation that the criteria to obtain the badge has been met looky here
[image: criteria has been met]
Have been awarded [image] in meta and have been awarded [image] in main.

Comment: The badge is now obsolete, thus [meta-tag:status-norepro]

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't have read it yet!! You need to expand (click on ***show more***) all the questions in [the FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) to receive the badge.

Otherwise, clicking on **all** the links in the sidebar should award you the [image: analytical] badge.

[image: faq-sidebar]

You may need to wait a couple of hours to receive it.

Comment: how did you embed the badge? i do not have the privilege of editing your post to have a look see!

Comment: @geezanansa: As an image :-)

Comment: Have tried both methods you have indicated several times even after clearing browser cookies cache etc still have not been awarded badge

Comment: @geezanansa: Then the system knows you are not reading them. Make sure you are reading the [faq] for the [main] site and not [meta]. If you have just performed these actions, then wait for a day or two. Also try a different browser. Otherwise, its out of our hands - mods would have to escalate the issue with the devs.

Comment: Then as i have been trying to obtain this badge for weeks i.e. "Have mentioned this in chat a few weeks ago" How do i ask mods "to escalate the issue with the devs"? or should this question be enough to bring the concern to the attention of appropriate people?

Comment: @geezanansa: I guess this question should be sufficient. This is what Meta is all about :-)

Comment: "Then the system knows you are not reading them." Can assure you i have studied them not just read them!  Suggest Edit: change "knows" to "thinks"

Comment: @geezanansa: I was just joking about it, don't worry about that too much. Right now the question is tagged as bug, so you should be receiving the badge in the near future.

Comment: This particular badge takes a while to arrive...